# MySql Replicate different tables to different database

Tags: mysql, replication

I have **Database1** on **server1** and **Database2**,**Database3** on **server2**.
**Database1** has two tables **T1**, **T2**. I want to replicate **T1 on Database2** and **T2 on Database3**.
How can I accomplish it?

I googled but only found examples where replication was performed to only one DB.

Comment: On MSSQL you could add the additional servers with [`sp_addlinkedserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190479.aspx) and then create views from the external tables. There should be an alternative for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You could make server2 as slave of server1. Server2 contains a replica of db1. Into db2 create a view that point to db1.t1, and int db3 create a view that point to db1.t2. I have attached an image to clarify.

[image: example]